# Сообщения между пользователями

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите организовать систему сообщений между пользователями. Сделал две таблицы dialogs и messages. На скринах таблицы dialogs и messages.

Можно ли как-то при выводе всех диалогов взять последнее сообщение из messages для соответствующего диалога и подставить данные к нужному диалогу при выводе всех диалогов. То есть выглядеть будет примерно как в VK. Сам пробовал и так и сяк, но все без толку. Это нужно, чтобы не создавать поля в dialogs text (текст последнего сообщения), date (дата посл. сообщения), которые потом еще и обновлять придется при добавлении сообщений в диалог.

[image]

[image]

Comment: все равно немного не то. Еще бы вытащить нужные данные из users для автора последнего сообщения в каждом диалоге, если такое возможно, было бы здорово

Comment: @sew810i9_I9, конечно, возможно. Я даже вам написал в комментарии, как это делается. Добавьте JOIN на вашу таблицу users.

Comment: Такой запрос получился: 

    SELECT * FROM dialogs
  INNER JOIN (SELECT dialog_id, MAX(message_id) AS max_message_id FROM messages GROUP BY dialog_id)
  max_messages ON dialogs.dialog_id = max_messages.dialog_id
  INNER JOIN messages ON messages.message_id = max_messages.max_message_id
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id=dialogs.to ||     users.id=dialogs.from WHERE users.id !={$userId}

Получается, я достаю из users данные для того, с кем беседа, а не для того, кто оставил последнее сообщение. А мне нужны данные и для собеседника и для того, кто оставил последний комментарий.

Comment: @sew810i9_I9, своим запросом вы множите строки. У вас диалогов получится в два раза больше (при условии, что оба поля from и to везде заполнены). Чтобы строки не множить, вам нужно сделать еще один JOIN. В итоге у вас должно получится 4 JOIN'а. Что-то вроде:

    'INNER JOIN users AS sobesednik ON users.id=dialogs.to INNER JOIN users AS latest_author ON users.id=message.from`

Comment: @sew810i9_I9, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
SELECT * FROM dialogs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT dialog_id, MAX(message_id) AS max_message_id FROM message GROUP BY dialog_id
) max_messages ON dialogs.dialog_id = max_messages.dialog_id
INNER JOIN message ON message.message_id = max_messages.max_message_id
```

Не проверял. Но надеюсь, что ничего не попутал.

UPD:

WHERE и нужно всего один раз писать. А насчет моделей - да. Одна модель User - это один пользователь и соответственно одна запись в таблице. А эта таблица в свою очередь может представлять собой только одного пользователя с его именем, фамилией, логином. Объясню, по-другому. Это еще нужно, чтобы на диаграммах базы данных правильно озаглавливать связи: user отправляет [много] message, dialog включает в себя [много] message и т.д. В этом случае, чтобы различать, что сообщений у пользователей может быть много или всего одно, применяют типы связей: один ко многим, один к одному.

UPD2:

[[@varz62](/users/4942/varz62)](/users/4942/varz62), мне в универе рассказывали про IDEF1X. Только что нашел отрывок из описания этого стандарта в оригинале. Цитата:

> The entity name is a noun phrase that describes the set of things the entity represents. **The noun phrase is in singular form, not plural**. Abbreviations and acronyms are permitted, however, the entity name must be meaningful and consistent throughout the model... Although an entity may be drawn in any number of diagrams, it only appears once within a given diagram.

http://www.idef.com/pdf/Idef1x.pdf, страница 8

Плюс ко всему, мне кажется удобным, когда название модели и таблицы совпадают. Зачем плодить неразбериху?

Comment: Dobby007, ошибка - Unknown column 'max_messages.message_id' in 'on clause'. Я сам не понимаю такой запрос, и для чего тут MAX используется?

Comment: Исправил. MAX используется, чтобы выбрать последнее сообщение для каждого диалога. У вас же AUTO_INCREMENT стоит на колонке message_id

Comment: Ошибка чуть глубже, в названии "message". "s" пропущено.

> Я сам не понимаю такой запрос, и для чего тут MAX используется?

Пора начинать уже.

П.С. Я бы прикинул еще такой вариант:

    SELECT m.dialog_id, MAX(m.message_id) AS last_message_id
    FROM messages m
    LEFT JOIN dialogs d ON d.dialog_id = m.dialog_id
    ORDER BY m.date DESC
    GROUP BY m.dialog_id

Comment: Это работает, а можно как то еще объединить это с таблицей users, чтобы вытащить имя пользователя, фото и т. д. и подставить их при выводе диалогов ? Вообще данные из users нужно получить имеено собеседника, а не свои, то есть в беседе участвуют двое, я и какой пользователь. Нужно подставить данные (фото и имя польз.) именно собеседника. В это самая сложность для меня

Comment:     Ошибка чуть глубже, в названии "message". "s" пропущено.

Пусть человек сразу учится правильно таблицы называть. Название всегда должно быть в единственном числе.

@VasyOk, это как подзапрос или что? Просто в вашем случае ничего, кроме идшников, не получишь.

Comment: Ох,чувствую я, копию контакта делаем... К моему запросу добавьте `INNER JOIN users ON message.user_id = users.user_id` и будет вам счастье. Только на свои названия исправьте.

Comment: хахаха. Да не, контакт точно не получится. Только сообщения хочу сделать на подобие VK. Про таблицы в единственном числе впервые слышу. Еще бы услышать довод, почему они должны быть в единственном числе

Comment: Это соглашение такое. Примите это как есть) Почитайте правила IDEF1X. Таблица представляет какую-то сущность со свойствами (колонками). Потом в MVC все модели представляют всего один объект. Он - в единственном числе. Будете называть по-разному - путаница получится.

Comment: а условие WHERE можно в таком объединенном запросе писать только один раз или как-то то при каждом inner join можно написать WHERE ?
Касательно модели не совсем понял, названия классов Вы имели ввиду? Типа не Users а User правильно?

Comment: @Dobby007 где это принято в единственном числе таблицы называть.
В большинстве случаев действует соглашение, что модель в единственном числе, а соответствующая таблица - во множественном.

Comment: Столько JOIN'ов, что ужас. Я бы хранил данные юзеров в redis, а не открывал бы таблицу users.